# WPF Pages of images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, view, listbox

So i'm new to WPF, and i'm trying to write an application that displays thumbnail previews from images in a folder, and have it if the user clicks on the thumbnail it displays the full image.

Now my first idea to implement this was to use a `ListBox` control and load them into that. But I want it, instead of scrolling when there's to many images to fit the screen, have a "Next Page" button to goto the next page of images, with a "Previous Page" button to go back.
And some nice transition effects when switching between the pages would be nice.
And i'm wondering if a `ListBox` is the best way to implement this?

I'd have to figure out how many images I could fit in the `ListBox`, and keep track of what images are on what page, and I have a feeling there's a easier way to do this.

Comment: You might also want to look at the [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in support for this kind of thing in WPF i.e. a control which  provide forward backward buttons for changing items all by itself. In my opinion `ListBox` is a nice control for your scenario and you can do one of the following to achieve your goal.

- Try to find a custom made `ListBox` control which supports your requirements on web and use it. Explore [this](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) open source library
- You can write your own logic as you said. A simple way could be to use two collections. One  with all the items and one with currently displaying.
- Use the simple `ListBox` but apply some custom template on it that will give it a new look. Make the scroll bar look like forward and backward button. It will appear to user that he is clicking next or back button but in actual all the work will be done by built-in Scroll Bar. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx) post for such kind of work